# Android - revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera-intent

I am opening Camera with `kotlin` like bellow:

```
private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        val photoFile: File? = try {
            activity?.createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            Timber.e(ex)
            null
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        photoFile?.also {
            takenPhotoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    requireContext(), "zz.zz.android.fileprovider", it
            )
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, takenPhotoUri)
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERFORM_CAMERA)
        }
    }
}
```

But get me bellow error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } clip={text/uri-list U:content://zz.zz.android.fileprovider/zz_zz_chat_images/PNG_%DB%B2%DB%B0%DB%B1%DB%B9%DB%B0%DB%B1%DB%B1%DB%B4_%DB%B1%DB%B4%DB%B2%DB%B2%DB%B5%DB%B5_1904526976.png} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{e956b7f 13929:zz.zz.android.dev/u0a1605} (pid=13929, uid=11605) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

I am using from `intent` for open camera.

And here is my `onActivityResult`:

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, resultData: Intent?) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode) {
                REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERFORM_CAMERA -> takenPhotoUri?.let { uri ->
                    uri.getBitmpap(requireContext())?.let { bitmap ->
                        presenter.uploadImage(chatRoomId, "image/png", uri, bitmap, "")
                    }
                }
}}
```

Comment: If you read the note here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Basically From Android Marshmallow the permission model have change for more detail you can check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous-permission-prompt So before starting intent for open camera you need to check whether permission is granted. For testing you can go into setting-->Permission of app in device and switch the camera permission. Then check it will not crash

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting. It will help you in coding.

Comment: You do not need the `CAMERA` permission to take a picture via `Intent`. However, if you do list the `CAMERA` permission in your manifest, and attempt to do so without having that permission granted, it will throw that Exception. This was done to prevent confusion for end users who try to manually disable that permission in an app's Settings. Simply remove the `CAMERA` permission from your manifest. You might need to clean/rebuild your project, and possibly uninstall/reinstall your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use camera permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and for above marshmallow run Time permission is required

like

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity)
                getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {


        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(), 
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }

    }
```

in onRequestPermissionsResult Check  is permission granted or not

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // main logic
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
}
```